# controller logic to update both name and photo (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to enable a user to update their first name as well as profile photo in the same view/controller, but separate models/forms/modals. If name updates, photo doesnt and vice versa.

When I try to update photo, I get in browser ActionController `param is missing or the value is empty: student` and nothing in the console. Here is my new html:

```
  =form_with model: @student_account  do |form|
        .form-group
            = form.label :task_name, "Name", class: "form-control-label"
            = form.text_field :first_name, id: "first_name", class: "form-control"
        =form.submit "  Update  ", {class: "btn btn-primary float-right"}
        button.btn.btn-secondary.float-right type="button" data-dismiss="modal" 
            = "Cancel"
 .modal-body
    =form_for @student, url: student_account_path, html: { multipart: true } do |form| 
        .form-group
            = form.label :image, "Image", class: "form-control-label"
            = form.file_field :image, id: "image", class: "form-control"
        =form.submit "  Upload  ", {class: "btn btn-primary float-right"}
        button.btn.btn-secondary.float-right type="button" data-dismiss="modal" 
            = "Cancel"
```

And my controller:

```
  def update   
    student_account = StudentAccount.find(params[:id])

    # if params[:image].nil?
    if params.has_key?(:first_name)
        logger.debug("hitting here!")
        if student_account.update_attributes(student_account_params)
            flash[:notice] = 'Preferred name updated successfully.'
            redirect_to(student_account_path(student_account.id))
        else
            flash[:alert] = student_account.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
            redirect_to(student_account_path(student_account.id))
        end
    else
        @student.update_attributes(student_image_params)
        flash[:notice] = 'Photo updated successfully.'
        redirect_to(student_account_path(student_account.id))
    end
end

  private

  def student_account_params
    params.require(:student_account).permit(
        :first_name,
        :image
      )
  end

  def student_image_params
    params.require(:student).permit(
        :image
      )
  end
```

Comment: You need to have only one form.

Comment: Why? I want them on separate modals

Comment: Because each form triggers a single request-response cycle. If you have two forms, then by definition, you will have two request-response cycles - one for each model. BTW, there is no reason a single form cannot update multiple models - either of similar or dissimilar classes. Models, controllers, and views (including forms) do not have a 1:1 relationship with each other.

Comment: Modals or models? (Not that it matters. You still need both on a single form is you want to update them in a single request.)

Comment: Both- I meant modals, but they are also different models. Hmm okay I will look at trying to make it one form with multiple modals and models...

Comment: Do you have another way of using 2 models to 1 form besides using fields_for? That appears how people have done it, but that completely blows away my image upload form

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'blows away my image upload form'. You could re-write your question (or post a new one) with the relevant detail and we could take a look. BTW, you don't *even* want to know how I do this sort of thing. It's complicated to set up, but awesome once you have it rockin'.

Comment: Hmm alright it's updated - thank you!

Comment: Please add your console output to your question. But, minimally, this stuff is almost certainly incorrect: `, url: student_account_path, html: { multipart: true }`. The `form_with` should determine the path. Specifying a second path doesn't make sense. One form. One path.

Comment: Updated again - Took out the url part but not multipart as I need that for image uploader. So then `form.fields_for @student` will still follow that path to the student account controller but use the student model?

Comment: Yes, as you said about `StudentAccountsController` and `Student` model. That error you posted doesn't look like server console output. The output in your console should start with something like: `Started POST "/student_accounts/23813a86-f412-441b-acfb-88fcdb688fa5" ...`

Comment: Okay the error was huge so i took out the table data but there is the meat of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it - all I had to change was the params_has_key in the if/else like so:

```
 if params.has_key?(:student_account)
        logger.debug("hitting here!")
        if student_account.update_attributes(student_account_params)
            flash[:notice] = 'Preferred name updated successfully.'
            redirect_to(student_account_path(student_account.id))
        else
            flash[:alert] = student_account.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
            redirect_to(student_account_path(student_account.id))
        end
    elsif params.has_key?(:student)
        @student.update_attributes(student_image_params)
        flash[:notice] = 'Photo updated successfully.'
        redirect_to(student_account_path(student_account.id))
    end
```